# Why regExp has diff results in diff senarios?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Simply speaking, in either node.js or in the browser, run the code below:

```
const sep = '\\';
const regExpression = `/b\\${sep}|a\\${sep}/`;
const testCases = ['a\\abb\\abc','b\\'];
const regTest = new RegExp(regExpression);

console.log(`Result for ${testCases[0]} is ${regTest.test(testCases[0])}`)
console.log(`Result for ${testCases[1]} is ${regTest.test(testCases[1])}`)
```

Both of the outputs are false:
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OUHmY.png)

however, if I change to this:

```
const regExpression = `/c|b\\${sep}|a\\${sep}/`;
```

Both of the results will be true....why?
[right](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PrwvH.png)

Another interesting thing is: The matching condition cannot be always the first, which takes '/c|b\${sep}|a\${sep}/' as an example, 'c' will NOT match.....

Comment: The final `regTest` to test with is `/\/b\\|a\\\//`, that would match `'/b\'` or `'a\/'`.

Comment: 'c' is ignored?

Comment: `c` is igneored, yes, there's no `c` in the regExp. Are the outmost `/`s actually intented to be the regExp separators like in a regExp literal? You should not include the separators in a string used with RegExp constructor.

Comment: Umm ... With "_final_" I meant the RexExp in the very first snippet in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is because of the regex itself.

```js
const regExpression = "/test/";
const regTest = new RegExp(regExpression);
console.log(regTest); // Regex: //test//

console.log(regTest.test("test")) // false
console.log(regTest.test("/test/")) // true
```

In the first case `/b\\\\|a\\\\/` -> regex -> `//b\\|a\\//`. The regex will try to find `/b\\` or `a\\/`. So will fail in both values.

```
'a\\abb\\abc'  => FALSE
'b\\'          => FALSE
'a\\/abb\\abc' => TRUE (a\\/ coincidence) 
'/b\\'         => TRUE (/b\\ coincidence)
```

In the second case `/c|b\\\\|a\\\\/` -> regex-> `/c|b\\|a\\/`. The regex will try to find `/c` or `b\\` or `a\\/`.

```
'a\\abb\\abc'  => TRUE (b\\ coincidence)
'b\\'          => TRUE (b\\ coincidence)
```

So, in conclusion you could solve your problem with:

```js
const regExpression = `b\\${sep}|a\\${sep}`;
```

This should try to find `b\\` or `a\\`. I don't know if this is the case but remember the `^` and `$` regex tokens too. You could make your tests in [regex101](https://regex101.com/).